# how to segregate all double and string data type into a collection of Instance

Tags: c#

Here are my class structure and sample data,

```
public class CollectionProperty
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public object Value { get; set; }
    public string DataType { get; set; }
}

public class Instance
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<CollectionProperty> CollectionProperties { get; set; }
}

public class CollectionResult
{
    public string Asset { get; set; }
    public List<Instance> Instances { get; set; }
}
```

===============================================================================================

```
var collectionResult = new CollectionResult
        {
            Asset = "A1",
            Instances = new List<Instance>
            {
                new Instance
                {
                    Name = "Instance-1",
                    CollectionProperties = new List<CollectionProperty>
                    {
                        new CollectionProperty {Name = "N1", Value = 10, DataType = "Double"},
                        new CollectionProperty {Name = "N2", Value = "S1", DataType = "String"}
                    }
                },
                new Instance
                {
                    Name = "Instance-2",
                    CollectionProperties = new List<CollectionProperty>
                    {
                        new CollectionProperty {Name = "N1", Value = 20, DataType = "Double"},
                        new CollectionProperty {Name = "N2", Value = "S2", DataType = "String"}
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

Now based on `DataType`, I want to segregate like below collection. Example is Double, similar for string. In `collectionResult`, I need to add `Asset` and all the double data type collection properties from various instances. IS this possible?

```
var collectionResult = new CollectionResult
        {
            Asset = "A1",
            DoubleInstances = new List<Instance>
            {
                new Instance
                {
                    Name = "Instance-1",
                    CollectionProperties = new List<CollectionProperty>
                    {
                        new CollectionProperty {Name = "N1", Value = 10, DataType = "Double"}
                    }
                },
                new Instance
                {
                    Name = "Instance-2",
                    CollectionProperties = new List<CollectionProperty>
                    {
                        new CollectionProperty {Name = "N1", Value = 20, DataType = "Double"}
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: Where is a complexity? You are not allowed to use `foreach` or delete/add items from `List`?

Comment: How about a couple of sentences of background to ease us into this problem and give us some context and make it easier to digest and understand.  As it stands, this comes off as a "wall of code" type question.  It also looks like you know basically how to do what you want.  Where did you run into problems?  What's the specific thing you need help with?

Comment: Is this just a query operation or do you need to create a copy of the CollectionResult and its Instances where the CollectionProperties have been filtered?  Did you start with a query like "CollectionProperties.Where(cp => cp.DataType == "Double")` ?

Comment: Do you need the whole `Instance` instance, with the `CollectionProperties` filtered to just the entries where `DataType == "Double"`? Or do you just need a method or property on `CollectionResult` that will return all `CollectionProperty` items where `DataType == "Double"` across all the items in `Instances`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this situation it would be straightforward to create a new `CollectionResult` instance and do the property filtering with LINQ. You could create new instances with [`Enumerable.Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8)and filter only Doubles with [`Enumerable.Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8):

```
var doubleCollection = new CollectionResult
{
    Asset = collectionResult.Asset,
    Instances = collectionResult.Instances.Select(x => new Instance { 
        Name = x.Name, 
        CollectionProperties = x.CollectionProperties.Where(cp => cp.DataType == "Double").ToList() 
    }).ToList()
};
```

You could also create a method to filter by a `Func<CollectionProperty, bool>` predicate selector. This approach can be useful if down the track you decide you want to filter by a different property from `CollectionProperty`. You can just pass in a different predicate.

```
private static CollectionResult FilterCollectionByProperty(CollectionResult collectionResult, Func<CollectionProperty, bool> selector)
{
    return new CollectionResult
    {
        Asset = collectionResult.Asset,
        Instances = collectionResult.Instances.Select(x => new Instance
        {
            Name = x.Name,
            CollectionProperties = x.CollectionProperties.Where(selector).ToList()
        }).ToList()
    };
}
```

And create both `CollectionResult` objects seperately or in `IEnumerable<CollectionResult>`:

```
var types = new List<string> { "Double", "String" };

// Separate collections
var doubleCollection = FilterCollectionByProperty(collectionResult, x => x.DataType == "Double");
var stringCollection = FilterCollectionByProperty(collectionResult, x => x.DataType == "String");

// List of collections
var collectionList = types.Select(t => FilterCollectionByProperty(collectionResult, x => x.DataType == t));
```

The other alternative is to pass in and filter by `DataType` directly, then you don't need to pass in the `Func<CollectionProperty, bool>` predicate. Downside is that the method is fixed to filtering by `DataType` only.

```
private static CollectionResult FilterCollectionByDataType(CollectionResult collectionResult, string dataType)
{
    return new CollectionResult
    {
        Asset = collectionResult.Asset,
        Instances = collectionResult.Instances.Select(x => new Instance
        {
            Name = x.Name,
            CollectionProperties = x.CollectionProperties.Where(cp => cp.DataType == dataType).ToList()
        }).ToList()
    };
}
```

Which also can be created into separate `CollectionResult` objects or a `IEnumerable<CollectionResult>`:

```
var types = new List<string> { "Double", "String" };

// Separate collections
var doubleCollection = FilterCollectionByDataType(collectionResult, "Double");
var stringCollection = FilterCollectionByDataType(collectionResult, "String");

// List of collections
var collectionList = types.Select(t => FilterCollectionByDataType(collectionResult, t));
```